# How to construct CoreData predicate to get all Activity(with location) where location.name = "ABC"?

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite, core-data

In my data model, I have:

```
Activity(name, sponsor, Location*) // one activity may have many Locations
Location(name, street, suburb, state, postcode)
```

And I need a way to get activities with specified location name, for example, user wants to know all activities in "ICT Building", so how do I construct the predicate for the query?

Something like:

```
"Location.name == ICT Building" ?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this where `managedObjectContext` is your context:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
    entityForName:@"Activity" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSString *locationName = @"ICT Building";
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Location.name CONTAINS %@", locationName];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

This will return an array with managed objects where the name is ICT Building.

Comment: Does it work if an Activity has many Locations? So the actual property of Location is a Set instead of just Location?

Comment: @hzxu It should (but I am not entirely sure) since Core data will find each Location.name in your object and search the name

Comment: I  tried but it does not work: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Change

```
@"Location.name == %@"
```

to

```
@"Location.name CONTAINS %@"
```

in @CoreCode's answer.